# Mysql cannot delete row

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to delete a row with phpymyadmin. When I click delete, this error appears:

SQL query:

```
DELETE FROM  `Sistema Informacion Abogados`.`Clientes` 
WHERE  `Clientes`.`DNIcliente` =  'asd'
```

> MySQL said: Documentation
>
> #1054 - Unknown column 'Clientes.DNIcliente' in 'where clause'

When I try to DELETE executing a SQL QUERY, the same thing happens. However, I can insert and edit. The column name is correct, the table name is correct. It has Foreign Keys but that restriction is at the moment disabled.

Mysql version 5.1.73

```
SHOW CREATE TABLES:

Clientes
CREATE TABLE `Clientes` (

 `DNIcliente` varchar(9) NOT NULL,

 `Nombre` varchar(20) NOT NULL,

 `Apellidos` varchar(40) NOT NULL,

 PRIMARY KEY (`DNIcliente`)
) 
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: Can you provide your schema for `Clientes`?

Comment: Provide the result of query: `SHOW CREATE TABLE Clientes;`

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ `Clientes` is a table not a schema

Comment: @DanFromGermany Ah, excuse me. My terminology is off :)

Comment: Added SHOW CREATE TABLE  Clients result

Comment: Created the table and used your query to delete on my local machine, everything ran smoothly.

Comment: @ramako Only thing left to ask is, are you sure you added the `SHOW CREATE TABLE Clientes` using the database `Sistema Informacion Abogados`?  `use Sistema\ Informacion\ Abogados;SHOW CREATE TABLE Clientes`

Answer (score 0):

Try this query :

```
DELETE FROM `sistema informacion abogados`.`clientes` WHERE `DNIcliente` LIKE 'asd';
```

or :

```
DELETE FROM `sistema informacion abogados`.`clientes` WHERE `clientes`.`DNIcliente` = 'asd';
```

Comment: Same result :( Its not finding the column, maybe it got corrupted or something.

Comment: if you are using phpmyadmin before run this query make sure about select your `Sistema Informacion Abogados` database

Comment: run this query CHECK TABLE `sistema informacion abogados`.`clientes`

Comment: Sistema Informacion Abogados.Clientes
check
status
OK

Comment: can you put print screen of your try to delete query ?